# How to Extract the Numerical value from a String

Tags: java, android

Im building an android application in which i want to extract only the numeric values(Rs.875) from the inbox message and add them all.
how can i do it please give some ideas.

example:The messages will be like this-
1> Recharge of Rs.196 for 9055668800 is successful. Recharge prepaid mobile instantly using freecharge app.
2>hi, we have received payment of Rs.2000.00 with ref.no.NF789465132. Stay tuned while we confirm your booking.

I have to calculate only the amount in from the text.

Comment: You want to extract all numeric values or just one numeric value?

Comment: @Mrunal just the amount (Rs.200)  of all the messages and i have to add all those amount together and generate a total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this: You can use `Regex` like `"(?<=Rs.)\\d+[\\.\\d]*"` to get only the amount as asked in the question. *I have to calculate only the amount in from the text.*

```
String message = "Recharge of Rs.196 for 9055668800 is successful. Recharge prepaid mobile instantly using freecharge app. hi, we have received payment of Rs.2000.00 with ref.no.NF789465132. Stay tuned while we confirm your booking.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Rs.)\\d+[\\.\\d]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
double sum = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    String digit = matcher.group();
    System.out.println("digit = " + digit);
    sum += Double.parseDouble(digit);
}
System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
```

And it is the out put:

```
digit = 196
digit = 2000.00
sum = 2196.0
```

Comment: Simple and perfect  unlike my answer

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera Thank you sir!

Comment: @BahramdunAdil What is your problem? Why you keep down-voting other answers? This is ridiculous.

Comment: @user2004685 At first that I did not down voted your answer? Second if you compare your solution with mine, then you will know that my solution is better than you, Yes your is also working, but he want to calculate the digits, in your answer it is possible to calculate it will throws NumberFormatException, it needs to gain use regex to extract the numbers. So it means that your solution is not better the others, cannot solve the problem completely. In such case you can up vote the answer which really solved the problem, and go ahead to answer the other questions. Thanks!

Comment: @user2004685 OK sir as you wish. I am down voting and up voting a lot of answers and questions everyday. Anyway I will up vote your answer now and wish you have nice and good time with your live! Thanks again!

Comment: @user2004685 It means that you do one job twice? haha it is not recommended, yes I know your answer is also OK, no problem, but it makes the more complex, do you know what I mean?

Comment: I mean that first you regex, and second you use substring operation, it means that you do two steps to solve the problem, but in my solution it just need only step. You delete your post and re post it again and I will up vote OK?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one without regex:

```
String[] messageParts = message.split(" ");
double sum = 0;

for (String messagePart : messageParts) {
    if (messagePart.startsWith("Rs.")) {
        sum += Double.parseDouble(messagePart.substring(messagePart.indexOf("Rs.") + 3));
    }
}
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

And the output is

> Sum: 2196.0

Answer (score -1):

If you want to extract only the recharge amount from the given String then you can use a Regex like `Rs.[0-9.]+`. You can then parse it to Integer or Double to sum it up.

Here is a quick code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String str = "Recharge of Rs.196.00 for 9055668800 is successful.";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("Rs.[0-9.]+");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
    double sumTotal = 0;
    if (m.find()) {
       System.out.println("Amount: " + m.group(0).substring(3));
       sumTotal += Double.parseDouble(m.group(0).substring(3));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Amount: 196.00
```

Comment: It is the best solution, but you can use `while` loop instead of `if` clause to check all the occurrence captured correctly.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. It should have been written as a comment .

Comment: @Praveen Really? Then how does rest of the answers make sense.

Comment: @user2004685 I was waiting for your reply dude, how you blindly rejected my edit on answer without spending much time on understanding the context, now you got that feeling ?  Now come to the point your answer doesn't make sense as it only address the given sample message only, he needs a solution for all messages to extract the total amount from it, something like a proper regx.

Comment: @Praveen Which Edit? Sorry I didn't get the Context?

Comment: That is because you can't add the extra information. You can add your own answer if you think it's correct. The decisions are made on majority of the votes. I'm not the only one who rejected it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104713/discussion-between-praveen-george-and-user2004685).